# Save latitude and longitude to Contact Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

There's a way to save a Location latitude and longitude in an contact intent?
I have something like:

```
        intent
            .putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, value);
```

There is a LATITUDE option? It is because i want to show this coordenates to a contact for show the exact location of this specific contact, for example:

[image]

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I thing it will help you first you have to get Full Address than you get Lat or Long :
http://www.androidauthority.com/get-location-address-android-app-628764/